# Errors in Faq-Request info

Tags: discussion, meta-faq

### This :

> [image]

- It should be "Your question[**s**]"
- *"from the functions"* does this even make sense phrased like that in this enumeration?

I know this is minor, but it's teasing my OCD. Also note that I'm not a native-English speaker, so the fact that these sound wrong to me doesn't mean I'm right.

Comment: @Servy Why should pictures be in a code block ?

Comment: A quote block. And for visual separation.

Comment: They're not in a code block, they're in a quote block, and they're in a quite block because, due to the white background and that the image contains nothing but text, it's difficult to determine what is content that you're quoting and what is your post; they blend right into each other.  The quote adds a border, thus making it clear what you are referencing and what is your commentary on it.

Comment: @Servy Nice thanks a lot I'll add this to my *edits routine* . I kept seeing it but was not sure why.

Comment: Feel free to [edit it yourself](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/44) - if two high rep (10K or 20K never remember here on Meta) will agree, it will pass.

Comment: I fixed the singular/plural issue. As for the "from the functions", that seems to imply a "to" at some point, which is missing. But the whole sentence is a bit of an ugly beast that might need some work. So I left that alone for now.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Woah didn't know I could do this. Thanks !

Comment: @Bart Good. And yes it feels kind of weird.

Comment: Yep it's like any tag wiki. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bart pointed out in the comments, it appears someone started a "*from ... to ...*" clause and never finished it. That sentence in general, though, was horribly formed and I don't even understand why comment replies were separated so severely like that. I also don't know what "the functions" was referring to, so I've just removed that.

I've rephrased the sentence as follows (still with appropriate links, of course):

> Your questions about how the site works (such as 10k user tools, reputation levels and comment replies) have been collected, collated and curated in these many posts.

While I was in there, I also changed the link next to the [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tag to not just say "tag the question with this tag" but actually point to the tag wiki for that tag which contains a full set of instructions for proposing a FAQ (which consist of more than just tagging).

Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: It does make a lot more sense now. Thanks !